# How to use javascript to find and replace a word split in a few tags?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to use javascript to find and replace a word which has been split in a few tags.

For example, the html code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="page-container">
            This is an apple.
            <div>
                <span>a</span><span>p</span><span>ple</span>.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the it looks like below in the web browser:

```
This is an apple.
apple.
```

I use this javascript to find and replace the word "apple":

```
var a = document.getElementById('page-container').innerHTML; 
a=a.replace(/apple/g,'pear'); 
document.getElementById('page-container').innerText=a;
```

But the result in the web browser is very bad, and all the tags could not work:

```
This is an pear.
<div>
<span>a</span><span>p</span><span>ple</span>.
</div>
```

It seems the replace function worked for the first row but cannot recognize the word split in the tags. This is an example, the whole content could be much more complex with more tags like , , not only ... Is there a way to replace only text but keep the original html tag format?

Comment: Yes, but you need to be clear about what html you expect to end up with.  The problem is because you read html, so you get all the tags.  You can read just the text, but doing so will remove all the html tags when it replaces the 2nd apple.

Comment: I want to replace the word and keep the tag format same. The content could be much more complex with more tags, not only <span>...

Comment: How do you define "the same format"? In your example, the first and second letter are wrapped in spans, while the remaining 3 letters are in one span. The replacement, "pear", doesn't have the same number of letters, so the best you can do is put spans around the first and second letters, and "the rest" will have one span. But that's not a consistent format, so chances are you don't want to hard-code it into your replacement. Without a consistent definition of the format you want to end up with, you can't do the replacement automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = document.getElementById('page-container').textContent;
a = a.replace(/apple/g, 'pear');
var a=a.split('.');
document.getElementById('page-container').innerHTML = `${a[0]}.<br/><span> ${a[1]} 
<span>`;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The whole content is much more complex with more tags, not only <span>... Is there a way to replace only text but keep the original tag format?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have nested  elements, so when you set innerHTML of the parent div, it treats inner div as text and print it out , try to replace this :

```
document.getElementById('page-container').innerText=a;
```

with this :

```
document.getElementById("page-container").firstChild.innerHTML = a;
```

So, you target only your first child which is parent div.

Live example:

https://jsbin.com/hujurageya/edit?html,js,output